# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter populateViewHolder NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am trying to populate **RecyclerViews** using **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter**. I am using **FragmnetPagerAdapter** to populate and have a three tabs layout using my ListFragment which contains the **RecyclerView**. I have catered for all the usual issues such as no empty constructor in the Model Class, Setting the layout manager using context e.t.c. but I am still getting a null pointer exception when the `protected void populateViewHolder()` function is called.

```
08-31 13:19:42.681 21993-21993/com.momskitchen.momskitchen V/MealListFragment:: mealname :Pakore
08-31 13:19:42.682 21993-21993/com.momskitchen.momskitchen E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.momskitchen.momskitchen.MealListFragment$3.populateViewHolder(MealListFragment.java:114)
at com.momskitchen.momskitchen.MealListFragment$3.populateViewHolder(MealListFragment.java:110)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:177)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5822)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5855)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5091)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4967)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3124)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1549)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:150)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:305)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

here is my Model Class

```
public class MealItem{
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public Long pricePerUnit;


    public MealItem() {
    }

    public MealItem(String id, String name, Long pricePerUnit) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
    }
}
```

here is my ViewHolder Class

```
public class MealHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    public final TextView mNameTV;
    public final TextView mPriceTV;

    public MealHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        this.mNameTV = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.meal_name_edit_text);
        this.mPriceTV = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.meal_price_text_view);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + mNameTV.getText() + "'";
    }
}
```

and this is where I try to populate the RecyclerView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meal_list, container, false);

    int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITON);
    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        if(position == 0){
            lunchListAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MealItem, MealHolder>(MealItem.class,R.layout.meal_item_layout_admin,MealHolder.class, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Meals").child("lunch")) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MealHolder viewHolder, MealItem model, int position) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "mealname :"+model.name);
                    viewHolder.mPriceTV.setText(model.name);
                    viewHolder.mNameTV.setText(""+model.pricePerUnit);
                }

            };
            recyclerView.setAdapter(lunchListAdapter);
        }else if(position == 1){
            dessertListAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MealItem, MealHolder>(MealItem.class,R.layout.meal_item_layout_admin,MealHolder.class, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Meals").child("dessert")) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MealHolder viewHolder, MealItem model, int position) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "mealname :"+model.name);
                    viewHolder.mNameTV.setText(model.name);
                    viewHolder.mPriceTV.setText(""+model.pricePerUnit);
                }


            };

            recyclerView.setAdapter(dessertListAdapter);
        }else if(position == 2){
            complimentListAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MealItem, MealHolder>(MealItem.class,R.layout.meal_item_layout_admin,MealHolder.class, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Meals").child("compliment")) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MealHolder viewHolder, MealItem model, int position) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "mealname :"+model.name);
                    viewHolder.mNameTV.setText(model.name);
                    viewHolder.mPriceTV.setText(""+model.pricePerUnit);
                }
            };
            recyclerView.setAdapter(complimentListAdapter);
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Also here is my RecyclerView xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.momskitchen.momskitchen.MealListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.momskitchen.momskitchen.MealListFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/meal_item_layout_admin" />
```

And here is my list item layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/meal_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/meal_price_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your " list item layout xml" doesn't have "R.id.meal_name_edit_text"
Thats why you are getting -->>NullPointerException

Comment: how stupid of me :P. Thanks a lot. Cheers :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)